# Structure the JSON object using group by in Postgres SQL

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to create structure using the Postgres SQL query. The structure is define to search faster for some advance functionalities of the application so that's why I couldn't change this structure and I guess this is the most viable structure for now.

**Table: provider_schedule**

```
|_id|user_id|day|start_time|end_time|hours_format|
|---|-------|---|----------|--------|------------|
|13 |87     |0  |09:00:00  |12:00:00|1           |
|14 |87     |0  |15:00:00  |20:00:00|1           |
|15 |87     |1  |09:00:00  |12:00:00|1           |
|16 |87     |1  |15:00:00  |20:00:00|1           |
|17 |87     |2  |15:00:00  |20:00:00|1           |
|18 |87     |2  |09:00:00  |12:00:00|1           |
```

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT day, jsonb_object_agg(start_time, end_time) as time_array, min(hours_format) as hours_format 
FROM provider_schedule 
WHERE user_id = 87 
GROUP BY day;
```

**Current result:**

```json
[{
    day: 0,
    time_array: {
      '09:00:00': '12:00:00',
      '15:00:00': '20:00:00'
    },
    hours_format: 1
  },
  {
    day: 1,
    time_array: {
      '09:00:00': '12:00:00',
      '15:00:00': '20:00:00'
    },
    hours_format: 1
  },
  {
    day: 2,
    time_array: {
      '09:00:00': '12:00:00',
      '15:00:00': '20:00:00'
    },
    hours_format: 1
  }
]
```

**Expected result:**

```json
[{
    day: 0,
    time_array: [{
        start_time: '09:00:00',
        end_time: '12:00:00'
      },
      {
        start_time: '15:00:00',
        end_time: '20:00:00'
      }
    ],
    hours_format: 1
  },
  {
    day: 1,
    time_array: [{
        {
          start_time: '09:00:00',
          end_time: '12:00:00'
        },
        {
          start_time: '15:00:00',
          end_time: '20:00:00'
        }]
      hours_format: 1
    },
    {
      day: 2,
      {
        start_time: '09:00:00',
        end_time: '12:00:00'
      },
      {
        start_time: '15:00:00',
        end_time: '20:00:00'
      }],
    hours_format: 1
  }
]
```

I want this expected structure from query. I don't want to use JavaScript to create this structure after query result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if the two rows for a day have a different hours_format?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  it won't have different hour format. All column of same row will be in same hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to levels of aggregation as you can't nest aggregate functions directly - which is what you need to get an array for the whole result and rows for one day as an array as well.

```
select jsonb_agg(single_day)
from (
  select jsonb_build_object('day', day, 
                            'hours_format', min(hours_format), 
                            'time_array', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('start_time', start_time, 'end_time', end_time) order by start_time)) as single_day
  from provider_schedule
  where user_id = 87
  group by day
) t
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6a0bd34f7ce1ec520b145a1fc7a78ccb)